# How to delete a git commit history when the branch is deleted?

Tags: git, github

Can someone let me know if it is possible to delete a git commit history completely? The branch in which the commit is present is deleted but the commit is still visible and I get a message like below

[image]

Comment: From where? GitHub? Probably not because they keep an audit log of everything. Locally you don’t directly delete things unless you do `git gc --prune=now` (and before that make sure that the commit is not reachable by the reflog).

Comment: AFAIK Github will periodically GC their repos and if it's not reachable via any tag/branch or fork, then that commit will eventually go away on its own.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32840254/7976758 : "**If you pushed to GitHub, force pushing is not enough, delete the repository or contact support**"

Comment: Github will probably automatically clean it up at some point ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments to the question I took this up with github support.

In this case, the PR that was raised was closed without being merged to any other branch, so the GitHub support deleted the closed PR history first and then the actual commit history.

Answer (score -3):

You should create a new branch and then add an empty commit to this new branch and if you force push to replace your new_branch with the old one you will not get anymore that commit message from the old branch.

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to achieve by working on an unrelated branch?